# In ggplot2 how to add angled label to donut chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below code can draw donut chart as the left one in attached image, how to change the label as the right one? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
pie_data <- data.frame(category=c('A','B','C'),sales=c(70,25,40))
pie_data %>% ggplot(aes(x=1,y=sales,fill=category))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_fill_brewer(direction = -1)+
  geom_text(position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),aes(label=paste0('Category ',category,':',sales)))+
  xlim(-1,2)+
  coord_polar(theta = 'y')+
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Check this package for ggplot2: https://github.com/AllanCameron/geomtextpath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `geom_textpath` from the geomtextpath package, which is now on CRAN. Essentially just replace `geom_text` with `geom_textpath` and set the angle to 90 degrees.

```r
library(geomtextpath)
library(dplyr)

pie_data <- data.frame(category = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                       ,sales = c(70, 25, 40))
pie_data %>% ggplot(aes(x = 1, y = sales, fill = category)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_brewer(direction = -1) +
  geom_textpath(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), angle = 90, size = 8,
            aes(label = paste0('Category ', category, ':', sales))) +
  xlim(-1, 2) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you are the author of the package `geomtextpath`. Aren't you?

Comment: @VishalA. Yes - I'm the co-author with Teun van den Brand

Comment: That's great! I just discovered this package and the results it is able to achieve are amazing!

Comment: Thanks, it's amazing . I just not understand  that why the angle value 90 ?  ('angle = 90')

Comment: @anderwyang it's because you are plotting with theta set to y. If you remove the coord_polar, you will see that the text needs to be vertical, in line with the stacked bars to wrap around in this direction. Try playing around with the angle to get a feel for this.